# How would Java know a specific undefined variable is integer?

Tags: java, java-8, jvm

What are the process that java uses to know a specific undefined variable is integer?

Comment: Use instanceof to check that

Comment: Defining variable means to *declare* it and *initialize* it. When you *declare* your variable, you provide its type.

Comment: Okay what do you mean by an 'undefined variable' ?

Comment: Java doesn't have "undefined variables".  It has uninitialized variables, and the way that Java would know that an initialized variable is an integer is because every variable has a type.

Answer (score 0):

For these types of a generic question, I will elaborate on some concepts used in Java Programming language and they are as follow:

1. Java is a **Statically typed language** where each variable and expression type is already known at compile time. Example `Integer intValue;`. So, Java doesn't support **Dynamically typed languages** as python where variables can be undefined and can receive different data types over time.
2. Java is also a **Strongly typed language** because types limit the values that a variable can hold or that an expression can produce, limit the operations supported on those values, and determine the meaning of the operations. Strong static typing helps detect errors at compile time.
3. A variable is a **storage location** and has an **associated type**, sometimes called its **compile-time type**, that is either a primitive type [(§4.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2) or a reference type [(§4.3)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3). From this concept, each variable knows its type at compile time and associate accordingly.

Please refer [Java Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html) for more clarity.